# I have two internship offers in Vienna can I apply for more than 180 days in total?

Tags: austria, working-visas

I got two internship offers from different organizations in UN in Vienna. One is 4 months and another one is 2.5 months. The thing is the note verbale will be strictly accorded to my internship agreements. I will apply the first visa-d first and then apply for the second visa. Is this possible to have two consecutive visas at the same time?? If possible, is it ok to stay more than 180 days with two consecutive visas? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: It might be better to ask on [expats.se]; that is where the expertise on each country's long-stay visa rules is concentrated.

Comment: Being slightly pedantic, how can something be both consecutive and ‘at the same time’ (simultaneous)? Am I missing something? My assumption is eg visa 1 expires at midnight and visa 2 starts at midnight + 1 minute, for example?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to have two consecutive visas at the same time?

Yes.

> If possible, is it ok to stay more than 180 days with two consecutive visas?

Yes.  With D-type visas the duration of your stay is limited only by the visa itself.